# Alignment Issue with Floats Next to Absolutely Positioned Elements Inside a List

Tags: css, alignment

I'm trying to place an absolutely positioned element next to a floating element. This seems to work, however the inline list element moves up.

To stop this from happening I can either take out the `float: right` or take out the `position: absolute`. The reason I need to use `position: absolute` is because my actual code relies on an image instead of the text "World".

How can I stop this from happening? The `clear: both` doesn't appear to be doing anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/wJF9T/2/

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <i>World</i>
            <span>Again</span>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background: aqua;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    width: 100px;
}

i {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

span {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle if you just  specify the alignment of the inline-block (`<li>`) like this

```
vertical-align: top;
```

or this

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

it fixes the problem. Not sure if it works in your context.

Comment: Strange. It does seem that forcing an alignment works, not sure why it's needed though.

Comment: My logic is that your '<li>' elements have a different perceived height (I guess it has to do with the floated element). By adding the rule you are just making sure the chosen alignment is the same for all the '<li>' so tada~ then it works.

Comment: Yeah still seems kinda hacky though. Wish I knew for sure how it's rendering.